# use variable in class A in class B by using A.__init__() method

Tags: python, class, variables, init

I'm trying to use a variable in `class A` in `class B` by using `__init__()` method. But somehow the variable in `class A` and B couldn't show up (no change in my cvs write file). Here is my code:

```
class Welcome(object):

   csv_name_sub = None
   csv_name_ses = None

   def __init__(self, master, csv_name_sub = None, csv_name_ses = None):
       self.entrySub=Entry(self.master,bg="grey")
       self.entrySes=Entry(self.master,bg="grey")

       self.csv_name_sub = str(self.entrySub.get())
       self.csv_name_ses = str(self.entrySes.get())

   def writeToFile(self):
       with open("/Users/Desktop/" + self.csv_name_sub+ '_' +   self.csv_name_ses + '_subjectNo.csv',
              'w') as resultFile:
       resultFileWrite=....

class App(Welcome):

    def __init__(self, master):
        Welcome.__init__(self, master) #I'm using python 3.5

        Welcome.csv_name_sub = str(self.entrySub.get())
        Welcome.csv_name_ses = str(self.entrySes.get())

        print('session is', Welcome.csv_name_ses)
        print("subject is", Welcome.csv_name_sub)

        self.resultFile = open("/Users/Desktop/" + Welcome.csv_name_sub + '_' + Welcome.csv_name_ses + '_results.csv', 'w')
```

The program can be run without an error, but `csv_name_sub` and `csv_name_ses` is empty when I print them in these two classes.

Comment: In Python, whitespace matters.  Can you check the formatting/tabbing of your methods?

Comment: Thans for your reminder Rocket, just changed that!

Answer (score 2):

The updated attributes are bound to the instance not the superclass. You should reference the attributes via the instance using `self`:

```
class App(Welcome):

    def __init__(self, master):
        Welcome.__init__(self, master) # Updated attributes are bound to self

        self.csv_name_sub = str(self.entrySub.get())
        self.csv_name_ses = str(self.entrySes.get())
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the attributes of the instance, i.e. from `self`:

```
class App(Welcome):

    def __init__(self, master):
       super().__init__(master) #I'm using python 3.

       print('session is', self.csv_name_ses)
       print("subject is", self.csv_name_sub)
```

Working example:

```
class Entry(object):

    def __init__(self, master, bg):
        pass

    def get(self):
        return 42


class Welcome(object):

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.entrySub = Entry(self.master, bg="grey")
        self.entrySes = Entry(self.master, bg="grey")

        self.csv_name_sub = str(self.entrySub.get())
        self.csv_name_ses = str(self.entrySes.get())

class App(Welcome):

    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)

        print('session is', self.csv_name_ses)
        print("subject is", self.csv_name_sub)


app = App('x')
```

Output:

```
session is 42
subject is 42
```

Comment: Thanks! The Entry(class Welcome) is a tkinter entry widget, what's entered here will be print in class App. `str(self.entrySub.get())` is get what users' input. I tried to incorporate your code to mine. But still `self.csv_name_ses` can't be print. Again, the program run fine without error. Do you have any idea why? Really appreciate it!

Comment: Maybe the result from `self.entrySub.get()` returns an empty string.